# Are modern Ubuntu installs compatible with ancient Kernel versions?

Tags: kernel, lts

On Ask Ubuntu we occasionally see people with problems like:

> I'm running 10.04 Lucid LTS on my toaster. I'd like to upgrade but I have expensive proprietary hardware that only has drivers for Lucid. I've tried later versions and my hardware doesn't work. The vendor went bankrupt 10 years ago. They wont write a new version of the driver.
>
> How do I `<something that involves something staying on 10.04>`

They're clearly in a bad spot. We don't support 10.04 for anything other than getting them to upgrade so a problem like that usually gets closed with a super-helpful "moan at the vendor" or "buy better hardware" comment.

Sounding a bit Meta, isn't it? Sorry. Here's the technical question...

### Could they use a recent LTS (eg 14.04, 16.04) with Linux 2.6?

It's not something I've tried (or have the time for right now) but at a simple level, could you:

- Install a modern version of Ubuntu
- Compile and install an ancient-but-maintained version of Linux from [kernel.org](https://kernel.org)?
- Remove the later kernels and actually run on 2.6
- Compile driver headers for 2.6

Would this work or are there bits in modern Ubuntu that depend on a modern Kernel?

The only other real solution I know at the moment involves pushing them off to CentOS, [which supports 2.6 into 2020](https://wiki.centos.org/About/Product). That's better than having a 10.04 desktop anywhere near the internet, but only just.

Comment: 16.04, I'd say a strong nope. systemd won't work, since it relies a lot on advancements in the kernel. Upstart, *maybe*.

Comment: Urgh systemd. Yeah its base requirements for Linux are currently `>= 3.7`.